Issues with import torch.nn
I'm trying to use my university server for more computing power, however, I'm struggling with importing torch.nn. I tried creating a new environment in the drive (to avoid having it installed in the default home), uninstalling torch and torchvision, and installing them again, and nothing seems to work.
>    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent
> call last) Cell In[5], line 1
> ----> 1 import torch.nn
> 
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\__init__.py:1
> ----> 1 from .modules import *  # noqa: F403
>       2 from .parameter import (
>       3     Parameter as Parameter,
>       4     UninitializedParameter as UninitializedParameter,
>       5     UninitializedBuffer as UninitializedBuffer,
>       6 )
>       7 from .parallel import DataParallel as DataParallel
> 
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\__init__.py:1
> ----> 1 from .module import Module
>       2 from .linear import Identity, Linear, Bilinear, LazyLinear
>       3 from .conv import Conv1d, Conv2d, Conv3d, \
>       4     ConvTranspose1d, ConvTranspose2d, ConvTranspose3d, \
>       5     LazyConv1d, LazyConv2d, LazyConv3d, LazyConvTranspose1d, LazyConvTranspose2d, LazyConvTranspose3d
> 
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:8
>       5 import weakref
>       7 import torch
> ----> 8 from torch._prims_common import DeviceLikeType
>       9 from ..parameter import Parameter
>      10 import torch.utils.hooks as hooks
> 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._prims_common'

I tried installing torch but I'm not sure where it went wrong. I can't import torch.nn nor check the version of torch. I'm doubting that attempting to run it on the server is part of the issue. I was expecting to be able to import torch.nn after the successful installation of torch.
Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated! Thanks.
